# Unable to update Navbar component without refreshing the entire page in angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a Navbar which has the following items:

Welcome

Admin

About

Source

Login

[image: I have attached a picture of the navbar]

The first time the user is about to login the value for login is "Login" and as the user navigates to  the Welcome component(or any other component) the value for login should change to the username passed.But on navigating to the Welcome component the value for the login on the navbar does not change and still displays "Login". Only when I refresh the page the username is displayed. Not able to figure out what's wrong

Below is what I have done:

navbar.component.html

```
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
         expanded="false">{{username}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="active"><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

navbar.component.ts

```
     constructor(http: Http, public router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.username = localStorage.getItem('username');

    this.authService.UserName.subscribe(value =>{this.username = value;});
    console.log(this.username)
```

Login.component.ts

```
      return this.authService.login(this.model.username, encrypted.toString())
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.authService.UserName.next("xyz");
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
            console.log(this.authService.UserName)
```

}

authentication.service

```
   public login(username: string, password: string) {
    let authHeader = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let body = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password });
    return this.http.post(this.endPoint.AuthenticationUrl, body, { headers: authHeader })
        .pipe(map((response: Response) => {

            this.username = response.json().username;
            localStorage.setItem('username', this.username);
        },
        (err) => {this.handleError; }));
}
```

I have tried component interaction and change detection. Pretty sure I am missing something but not sure what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is actually a drop down...this <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="active"><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>

Comment: yes the navbar html is there

Comment: i'm seeing only class="dropdown" element

Comment: <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
         expanded="false">{{username}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="active"><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

Comment: add full code for your navbar including, currently you have added only for username and logout. or you can create a StackBlitz example.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my case I am able to show the user detail but when  I logged out and again logged in then old user's name is visible. need to refresh the browser tab to show new logged in user name.

Comment: Hi Abhishek. Welcome :) please update your answer with details as to how this solves the OP’s issue. Otherwise it may be more suited as a comment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31512978)